# It's confusing where to put init code

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a UIView, for which I implemented the `init` method. This works for me because I always initialize my UIViews with the simple code below.

```
MYView *view = [[MYView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:view];
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,99,99)];
```

QUESTION: Can this view be used with storyboards? or do I need to implement other "init" methods? Also, what happens if someone instantiates the view with `initWithFrame`? Do I need to implement all the "init" methods to handle all these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboard and XIB files will use the `initWithCoder:` methods.